# CSS SlideIn animation without setting height

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I'm wanting to replicate the jQuery slideIn and slideOut, with CSS.

```
ul {  
  background-color:yellow;
  transform-origin: top;
  transition: transform .5s;
}

.slider {
  transform: scaleY(0);
}
```

The `.slider` class will force the UL element to resize. However my method does not account for the height. I want the height to resize to 0 so the button in my example, would move up.

Here is a JSBIN: http://jsbin.com/zoqiciwicu/1/edit

Is this even possible through CSS? I do not have a set height to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the `height` of the element is vary, one possible option could be to set [`max-height`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/max-height) property instead with a high value and use [`transition`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition) in order to achieve the animation:

**[Updated Example](http://jsbin.com/juwoxe/2/edit?html,css,js,output)**

```
ul {  
  background-color:yellow;
  transform-origin: top;
  transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
  max-height: 50em;
}

.slider {
  transform: scaleY(0);
  max-height: 0;
}
```

Preview:

```js
$('input').click(function(){   
    $('ul').toggleClass("slider"); 
});
```

```css
ul {  
  background-color:yellow;
  transform-origin: top;
  transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
  max-height: 50em;
}

.slider {
  transform: scaleY(0);
  max-height: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>test</li>
  <li>test</li>
  <li>test</li>
  <li>test</li>
  <li>test</li>
  <li>test</li>
  <li>test</li>
  <li>test</li>
</ul>    
<input type="button" value="slide">
```